# recurrence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the sequence defined by

$u_0=\frac{3}{2}$

$u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(u_n^3-3u_n^2+4u_n)$

I proved that $\forall \ n \ \in \ \mathbb{N}, u_n \geq 1$, and $(u_n)\rightarrow 2 $.

I would like to prove that $\forall \ n \ \in \ \mathbb{N^*}, u_{n+1}-u_n$ has the same sign that $u_{n}-u_{n-1}$

How could we do it ?

Thank you

Comment: Some of your findings would need to be explained in details ($u_n \geq 1 \forall n$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n=2$...).

Answer (score 2):

You could try analysing $$u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac 12(u_n^3-3u_n^2+2u_n)=\frac 12u_n(u_n-1)(u_n-2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x^3-3x^2+4x}{2}, x > 1$ has $f'(x) = \dfrac{3x^2-6x+ 4}{2} > 0, \forall x$. Thus $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and we have: $u_1 =1.31 < 1.5 = u_0 \Rightarrow u_n - u_{n-1} < 0 \Rightarrow u_{n+1} = f(u_n) < f(u_{n-1}) = u_n \Rightarrow u_{n+1} - u_n < 0$, and they have the same sign as claimed.